# limitaion for editing profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

how can I set limitaion times for users to edit their profile  ?

for example, they should have only 2 chances to edit address. and if they edit address 2 times, this field would be disabled next time they open the edit page.

my model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='حساب کاربری')
    mobile = models.CharField('تلفن همراه', max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField('آدرس', null=True, blank=True, max_length=5000)
```

and view:

```
def profile_edit(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if profile_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
        profile_form.save()
        user_form.save()
        return redirect('accounts:profile_details')
return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

Comment: Can you share your current profile model and update view?

Comment: You could simply have a `TimesEdited` field on the model, which you don't include on the corresponding form but which you update manually after editing, and check the value of to determine whether to disable fields.

Comment: @RobinZigmond  I edited my question and added model and view. could you please explain more about `TimesEdited` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `times_edited` variable to your model.

**models.py**

```
class Profile:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='حساب کاربری')
    mobile = models.CharField('تلفن همراه', max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField('آدرس', null=True, blank=True, max_length=5000)
    times_edited = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
def profile_edit(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    disable_edits = False
    if request.user.profile.times_edited > 2:
        disable_edits = True
else:
    profile_form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if profile_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
        profile_form.save()
        user_form.save()
        request.user.profile.times_edited = request.user.profile.times_edited + 1
        return redirect('accounts:profile_details')
return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', {'profile_form': profile_form, 'user_form': user_form, 'disable_edits': disable_edits })
```

Then use the `disable_edits` either in your template or as part of an API (depending on whether you are using the built in template engine or a JS framework).

EDIT: here is a way to check it in the backend

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    if User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk).profile.times_edited > 2:
        raise ValidationError("Email can no longer be edited")
    return User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk).email
```

To get requests into your form, you would need to do something like this from this blog:

https://brunobastos.net/how-to-access-the-httprequest-object-in-django-forms/

You can read more about form validation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/).

Comment: thanks, but I have a question. assume that I used `disable_edits` in my template and made the field disable, but the user can simply remove the attribute 'disabled' from the input tag and update it... so I need a validator in the backend... ` def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].disabled = True`

Comment: for example, the preceding code in a ModelForm will make email field disable, and if the user removes 'disabled' attribute in the browser and update it, the new value will not be saved in the database. how can I check the value of field 'times_edited' in forms.py  ? this should be safer